# Navigation history from local frame to global

Tags: c#, uwp

I have global frame, where i have NavigationView. So, in NavigationView i has create local frame.

```
<NavigationView
...
    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame">
        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <NavigationThemeTransition />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
    </Frame>
</NavigationView>
```

For navigate to the pages, i use someone like this:

```
switch (item.Tag)
{
    case "home":
    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage), ContentFrame);
    break;
    ...
```

ContentFrame is sent to ViewModel, where used for navigation inside the page.
When i navigate in this frame, history of navigation is't available in global frame. I want the click on the backstack button in the global frame to return me back to the local frame. But it button doesn't work, because global frame is't haven't history of local frame:
[Activate BackStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0IDv.jpg)

How can i do that?

Comment: Please share some code, screenshots or example

Comment: @MartinZikmund Thanks you for the comment. Well, I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title bar back button is handled by the `SystemNavigationManager.BackRequested` event.

I would suggest to store the `Frame` inside your `NavigationView` somewhere as a reference - for example by creating a property in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public Frame AppFrame { get; set; }
```

And set it like this:

```
( Application.Current as App ).AppFrame = frame;
```

And then implement the `BackRequested` event for example in `OnLaunched` in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += App_BackRequested;

private void App_BackRequested(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if ( AppFrame.CanGoBack )
    {
       AppFrame.GoBack();
       e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```